# Where can I see my NFT?

Tags: nft

Recently bought a NFTea from [here](https://cardanonftea.com/), where do I go to check out the actual image? Is there a Cardano NFT explorer or similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find your transaction, look at it on cardanoscan.io to get the policy_id and token_name, adjust the following link `https://pool.pm/<policy_id>:<token_name>`, and you'll see it.

Comment: Awesome! You were a bit unclear on the pool.pm link, took me a while to understand, can I suggest you edit the link like this instead?

https://pool.pm/<policy_id>:<token_name>

Answer (score 4):

You can also go to https://pool.pm and just enter your wallet address. It will show you the balance, plus all the native tokens. If any of them contain an IPFS address (like a picture for an NFT), then that will show up as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter any used address or stake address here: https://cardano-tools.io/my